# How do I set the application badge number in react native, iOS home screen?

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like to set the application badge number in my react native app. So this would be the red circle count number that appears on the app in the home screen for iOS. I have managed to achieve this using tabBarBadge in my Tab screen but how can I do the same on the app in my iOS home screen?

[image]

Would it be this PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(number) in the link https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios ? If so, where do I put this?

Thanks.

Comment: try onesignal for push notifications

Comment: Hi, can this not be achieved with react native and firebase?